# Android's context in non-activity unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-volley, android-instrumentation

I'm going to test my singleton `OcRequestQueue.java` class, which I want to be Volley's lasting the lifetime of the app `RequestQueue`. The problem is that it needs application's `context` which is beyond the class' scope, as I want to implement separate presentation and data layers, and `OcRequestQueue.java` is in the second one. Presentation layer is not implemented yet, so I want to perform unit test on what I've done, so I wanted to get the `context` from `InstrumentationTestCase`, but all I get is `!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected`. How can I perform unit tests on classes which don't extend `Activity`?

**com.data.OcRequestQueue.java**

```
package com.data;
import android.content.Context;
import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Network;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;


/**
 * Created by mateusz on 03.01.15.
 */
public class OcRequestQueue {
    static RequestQueue requestQueue;
    static Context mContext;
    static Cache cache;
    static Network network;

    private static OcRequestQueue ourInstance = new OcRequestQueue();

    public static OcRequestQueue getInstance(Context context) {
        if (ourInstance == null) {
            mContext = context;
            requestQueue = getRequestQueue(mContext);
        }
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private static RequestQueue getRequestQueue(Context context) {
        cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024);
        network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
        return new RequestQueue(cache,network);
    }

    public OcRequestQueue() {

    }
}
```

**com.data.test.OcRequestQueueTest.java**

```
package com.data.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;
import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;

import com.data.OcRequestQueue;



public class OcRequestQueueTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    Context context;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        context = getInstrumentation().getContext();
    }

    public void testGetInstance() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(new OcRequestQueue(), OcRequestQueue.getInstance(context));
    }
}
```

**bulid.gardle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.inject:guice:4.0-beta5'
    def domainLayer = project(':domain')
    //project dependencies
    compile domainLayer
}
```